# QML: threading model for WorkerScript

Tags: qt, concurrency, qml, worker

When using a QML `WorkerScript`, are the requests (sent via `postMessage()`) queued (and executed on a single handler thread) or is there the possibility/danger that two successive `postMessage()` will be executed on two threads concurrently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

All `WorkerScript` should execute in the same thread.

### Not so short answer

All `WorkerScript` in a `QQmlEngine` should execute in the same thread.

### Long answer

When you create a `WorkerScript` in QML you instantiate the `QQuickWorkerScript` C++ class. This class uses the `QQuickWorkerScriptEngine` class to handles all the thready things.

Now, if you look at [`QQuickWorkerScript::engine()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/types/qquickworkerscript.cpp.html#_ZN18QQuickWorkerScript6engineEv) and [`QQmlEnginePrivate::getWorkerScriptEngine()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/qml/qqmlengine.cpp.html#_ZN17QQmlEnginePrivate21getWorkerScriptEngineEv) you will see that all `WorkerScript` objects will share the same `QQuickWorkerScriptEngine` instance as long as they share the same `QQmlEngine`.

Also `QQuickWorkerScriptEngine` is a `QThread` (public inheritance) and contains a member variable named `d` of type `QQuickWorkerScriptEnginePrivate *`. `d` is running in the thread handled by `QQuickWorkerScriptEngine` (see `d->moveToThread(this)` in `QQuickWorkerScriptEngine` constructor). And it is this `d` that will effectively run the asynchronous work in [`QQuickWorkerScriptEnginePrivate::event()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/types/qquickworkerscript.cpp.html#_ZN31QQuickWorkerScriptEnginePrivate5eventEP6QEvent).

### PS

This kind of contradicts [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html#details) that states:

> Use WorkerScript to run operations in a new thread.

Which might make you think that each `WorkerScript` is a new thread.

Comment: "Which might make you think that each WorkerScript is a new thread" Yeah, that's what has prompted me to ask the question. For the future, a thread pool size for WorkerScript would be nice for cases where more than one executor is desirable.